# Creating new Array in Javascript adds 'unique' key

Tags: javascript

i'm using a wordpress plugin called DW Question and Answer. I have tried to 
change some behaviour and stumbled upon this odd problem:

```
var arr = [];
alert(arr['unique']);
```

this alerts:

```
function (){
"use strict";
for(var e=[],i=0;i<this.length;i++)-1==t.inArray(this[i],e)&&e.push(this[i]);return e}
```

Why is the 'unique' key set with that function?

In another test page on the same system (outside wordpress ) the same code alerts 'undefinded' as expected...

I'm curious to knwo how it is possible to set some keys when creating an empty array.

Comment: That's not a key. That's custom `Array`'s method which has been added by the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there's a plugin that modified the native `Array`s prototype to add custom members. That's usually a very bad practice.

Still, here's how it's done:

```
Array.prototype.someMember = 'test';

[].someMember; //test
```